# Actual width of an element with JQuery in Chrome ver. 30

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I use JQuery 1.10.1

I noticed that in Chrome ver. 30 changed how `$('selector').width()` function calculates the actual width of an element. For example, if I had an element like this:

```
...
<tr>
    <td id="my">
       some text123
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

and execute `$('#my').width()` it returned some positive number, equal to the width of `some text123` in `px`.

Then if I set width with `$('#my').css('width', '1px')` and executed `$('#my').width()` it still returned a positive number, but less then before - now it was equal to the  width of `text123` in `px`. It was a desired behaviour and worked for months.

Now when execute `$('#my').css('width', '1px')` the `$('#my').width()` returns `1`, or if execute `$('#my').css('width', '2px')` the result be `2`. This is not true, because actual width of a `<td>` element is bigger and is equal to `text123` in `px`.

Does anyone know is this a bug or desired behaviour in Chrome? I have tried IE 10, FF 24, Safari 5.1.7 - the `$('#my').width()` function in all these browsers works as expected.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appeared, this strange behaviour was fixed by Chrome team in a week after I asked the question. Now it works like expected.